# No JS added on form Drupal 7

Tags: javascript, forms, drupal-7

I'm trying to add JS file to my registration form. I modified it on my templates file, use the attached attributes for form but no js added

I searched a lot into google and read a lot of articles and solutions but no one of theme work for me and I don't know why. I work with Drupal 7.

```
if($form_id == 'user_register_form' ) {

        $form ['#attached'] ['js'] = array (drupal_get_path ( 'theme', 
                'wowork' ) . '/js/prova.js' );
    }
```

and my js file is

```
$(function () {
    Drupal.behaviors.form_cuentacorriente = {
        attach: function (context, settings) {
            console.log("ciao");
        }); 
    }
});
```

no console.log appear in developer tools google. Can someone know why?

Comment: Which version of drupal are you using? In drupal 7 you can't use hooks from the theme. You need to create a module.

Comment: I use Drupal 7. Do I need to create a module for the form? Can you explain me better?

Comment: I did it but nothing change... the js prova.js isn't added and no console.log appear in developer console

Comment: SOLVED: I created a module with a js directory. I moved js into this directory and after declared it on .info  with scripts[] = js/prova.js. Now it's visible. Thank you for your help @David Lemon:)